# HTML header has unnecessary padding on the left

Tags: padding

I have a header with two images that move together over time. The problem I have is that the image to the left looks okay on large screens but as the width comes in the left image starts to go off the screen. I have tried the -webkit-padding-start code to no avail,any help please. The code I have in my header is

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" id="countdown-header">
    <div class="pull-left" style="overflow: hidden;" id="width-left">
        <img align="right" id="steve-header">
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right" style="overflow: hidden;" id="width-right">
        <img align="left" id="lisa-header">
    </div>
    <div id="width-id" class="display-center text-countdown">
        <span id="days"></span><br>
        <span id="hours"></span><br>
        <span id="minutes"></span>
    </div>
</div><!-- end of row -->
```

Thank you

Comment: A screenshot of your issue would be extremely helpful, as well as the CSS styles related your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it turned out that the background-size property was causing me issues. On each of the images (left and right) I had background-size: 80% and then 40% in media queries in the CSS.

Once I removed them and re-sized the image instead all was well.

Thank you for your time.